# antd form: find out if initial value changed

Tags: forms, antd

I have a antd form which have initial values. I want to conditionally render a reset button if any of the value changed. Is there a way to find out is any value changed?

Answer (score 0):

In the version 4. The ANTD form can only load the initial values when the form is rendered first time. Then whatever the initialValues changes, the form cannot change correspondingly through set initialValues in the  tag

You can detect the initialValues changing by using useEffect

> useEffect(() => {
> form.resetFields()
> form.setFieldsValue({
> name: 'xxxx'
> })   }, [initialValues]);